# Python3 C Library usage

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a Python program from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5.  This program is including C libraries. The calls of the C libs are no longer working but it raises no error messages. What do I have to change that it is working in Python3?

```
class Yasdi:
    """YASDI Wrapper fuer Python"""
    def __init__(self,yasdi_lib="libyasdi.so",maxDriverIDs=10,DriverNameBuffer=30):
        """Konstruktor
                Parameter:
                yasdi_lib = "libyasdi.so"       |erwartet Pfad zur yasdi Lib
                maxDriverIDs = 10               |Anzahl der max. moegleichen Schnittstellen
                DriverNameBuffer = 30           |Anzahl der max.Namenslaenge des Schnittstellennamens"""
        self.maxDriverIDs = maxDriverIDs
        self.DriverIDArray = array.array("L",[0]*self.maxDriverIDs)
        self.DriverNameBuffer = " "*DriverNameBuffer

        self.yasdi = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(yasdi_lib)

    def yasdiGetDriver(self):
        """Gibt die Anzahl zur verfuegung stehender Schnittstellen zurueck"""
        result = self.yasdi.yasdiGetDriver(self.DriverIDArray.buffer_info()[0],self.maxDriverIDs)
        return result

    def yasdiGetDriverName(self,driverID):
        """Gibt den Namen eine Schnittstelle zurueck, zum Beispiel: COM1 oder /drv/ttyS0 etc.
                Parameter:
                driverID = erwartet Schnittstellnummer (z.B. 0)"""
        self.yasdi.yasdiGetDriverName(driverID,self.DriverNameBuffer,len(self.DriverNameBuffer))
        return self.DriverNameBuffer.replace("\x00","").rstrip().lstrip()

    def yasdiSetDriverOnline(self,driverID):
        """Setzt eine Schnittstelle(driver) online, Achtung: unter Linux muss die Schnittstelle freigegeben werden!
                Parameter:
                driverID = Nummer der Schnittstelle (Com1 = 0 etc.)
                Rueckgabe:
                0: bei Erfolg
                1: bei Fehler"""
        result = self.yasdi.yasdiSetDriverOnline(driverID)
        return result

    def yasdiSetDriverOffline(self,driverID):
        """Gibt die Schnittstelle wieder Frei
                Parameter:
                driverID = erwartet Schnittstellnummer (z.B. 0)"""
        self.yasdi.yasdiSetDriverOffline(driverID)
```

Comment: What does "no longer working" mean if there are no errors? What *does* happen? Where is the code you are trying to convert? How can we help with zero details?

Comment: I added some code - hope this helps!

Comment: The code is running in Python35 but the calls to the C lib do not return right values. When I run the same with Python 2.7 everything runs fine.

Comment: Or is there a change in Python3 with ctypes or C arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is fine - the problem was on a different part. Please be aware that strings in Python 3 are Unicode by default - that was my issue!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of binding. If it is a C binding, you will have to adapt it to the Python 3 interface and recompile. If it's bound via ctypes, you will want to go over the changes in that module.

Comment: I included a code part above. It seems for me it's ctypes - what I have to change?